# Fetching mail provider type in outlook web-addin

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-api

I need to differentiate between enterprise and office365 email in outlook web addin.

I am trying to do the same using email provider type. But, as per [office documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/preview/Office.context.mailbox.userProfile), *AccountType* in Office.context.mailbox.userProfile is only supported in Outlook 2016 for Mac, build 16.9.1212 and greater.

Is there any other way I can differentiate between these two email types? 
or get provider type for old native email clients in mac as well as windows? 
Can I use [ews url](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/preview/Office.context.mailbox) in office.context.mailbox in any manner?

Comment: when you say email provider, are you trying to figure out whether the user is Exchange on-prem vs Office 365 vs Outlook.com, or something else?

Comment: Yes. we are trying to identify whether user is on-premise or office 365

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. But you could use Mailbox version to support different things for different clients.

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between the two? It would help to understand the scenario you are trying to achieve after getting that information. Ews Url can be parsed to check for "outlook.office365.com" or "outlook.office.com" to indicate a Office365 account type. Those urls are different for some environments and inferring is not accurate and hence EWS Url is not a recommended way but you can use it as a workaround till those clients move to a recent build that supports Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.accountType