# Determining `accountType == office365` on iOS or Android Outlook Add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on an Outlook Add-in that has additional features for user that have a mailbox provided by their Microsoft 365 subscription.

For the most part we can detect Microsoft 365 subscriptions using the following call in office.js `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile?.accountType == 'office365'`. This works using the `accountType` property added in [requirement set 1.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/outlook-requirement-set-1.6) and above. To support mobile users is there an alternative way of doing this detection on Outlook for iOS or Android which only currently supports [requirement set 1.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets#outlook-client-support)?

Comment: With further reading I found this comment on a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155326/fetching-mail-provider-type-in-outlook-web-addin#comment85414030_49155326 from the Outlook Add-on team. It suggests using `Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl == 'outlook.office365.com'` as a proxy for `Office.context.mailbox.userProfile?.accountType == 'office365'`. But suggest there may be additional URLs that need to be checked.

Comment: It appears that `Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl` isn't populated correctly on iOS and Android builds. So the work around suggested above doesn't work.

Comment: Yes confirmed that `Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl` isn't available on iOS or Android apps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#ewsUrl .

Comment: There is another article that suggests using `Office.context.mailbox.restUrl` which does present correctly on Mobile versions of Outlook. However with some more investigation and testing Outlook.com presents using one of the standard Microsoft 365 endpoints so I can't tell the difference between an Outlook.com account and a Microsoft 365 subscription using this technique. Using `mailbox.ewsUrl` and `mailbox.restUrl` have both turned out to be dead ends.

Comment: **UPDATE** We've given up trying to resolve this in the front-end and instead made an API service call to check to see if the customer has the features provided by Microsoft 365 support.